# Screen rotation when launching PyQt5 application on linux without X server

Tags: pyqt5, orientation, touchscreen, xorg, screen-rotation

I have orangepi4 running on ubuntu server without xorg and mipi display for it. By default, the screen orientation is portrait.
I have developed a PyQt5 application that, when launched with an hdmi monitor connected, displays correctly with landscape orientation. But when switching to the mipi display, it is displayed with portrait orientation. Is there a way to make it work on a mipi display (with a touchscreen) with landscape orientation (i.e. make a 90 degree rotation)? Maybe I should modify the application code or install xorg without a desktop environment, or something else.

Running pyqt5 app:

```
QT_QPA_PLATFORM=linuxfb python3 run.py
```

I tried to find the PyQt5 code that will allow to rotate the entire screen of the application, I also tried to rotate the screen using fbcon (this works for the console, but when the application is launched, it is displayed with portrait orientation)

Example application:

```
import sys
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QWidget, QLabel

def window():
   app = QApplication(sys.argv)
   widget = QWidget()
   textLabel = QLabel(widget)
   textLabel.setText("Hello World!")
   textLabel.move(100,100)
   widget.show()
   sys.exit(app.exec_())

if __name__ == '__main__':
   window()
```

View:
[image on the HDMI monitor and MIPI-DSI touchscreen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2ABgd.jpg)

Comment: Sorry but we need more context. How are you getting the orientation? Are you using QScreen? Please provide a valid [mre].

Comment: You didn't answer all the questions I asked you. Besides, do you know about the [`tabletTracking`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qwidget.html#tabletTracking-prop) property (which should probably be set for the top level window)?

Comment: I don't get the screen orientation and don't use QScreen in the app. My application is designed for a regular monitor with landscape orientation and I want it to also work on a MIPI-DSI monitor, but it doesn't work as it should, I just want to rotate the screen 90 degrees. but I don't understand how